# Making boolean variable available in parent scope

Tags: angular, video.js

Given the component below

```
export class VideoPlayerComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('videoPlayer', { static: false })
  videoPlayer: ElementRef;

  @Input()
  videoUrl: string;

  @Input()
  videoType: string;
  /** Subject that emits when the component has been destroyed. */

  @Output()
  onPlayerEvent = new EventEmitter<VideoPlayerEvent>();
  videoJsPlayer: videojs.Player;
  showTimestamp: boolean = false;
  timeStamp: string;

  constructor() { }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.videoUrl) {
      const self = this;
      this.videoJsPlayer = videojs(this.videoPlayer.nativeElement, {}, function () {
        this.on('play', () => self.onPlayerEvent.emit('play'));

        this.on('pause', () => self.onPlayerEvent.emit('pause'));

        this.on('ended', () => self.onPlayerEvent.emit('ended'));
        return hls;
      });
      const myButton = this.videoJsPlayer.controlBar.addChild("button");
      const myButtonDom = myButton.el();
      myButtonDom.innerHTML = "<i class=\"material-icons\">\n" +
                              "query_builder\n" +
                              "</i>";

      // @ts-ignore
      myButtonDom.onclick = function(){
        console.log('click');
        this.showTimestamp = !this.showTimestamp;
        console.log(this.showTimestamp);
      };
    }
  }
}
```

I am attempting to toggle the 'showTimestamp' variable whenever the onclick event occurs. This appears to be updating within the scope of 'function(){}' however this is not updating in the scope of the component overall.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues with your non-Angular approach.

The main issue is a classic Javascript issue - `this` in functions declared like: `function() { }` refers to the function itself. To refer to the outer scope you should declare functions using arrow notation.

```js
myButtonDom.onclick = () => {
  console.log('click'); 
  this.showTimestamp = !this.showTimestamp;
  console.log(this.showTimestamp);
};
```

**BUT** you shouldn't be manually manipulating the DOM in an Angular project anyway. You would build your HTML dynamically and bind click events to their handlers in the HTML.

I have no idea of what your HTML requirements are, but you would bind click handlers like this:

```html
<button (click)="myClickHandler()">
 Click me
</button>
```

Comment: hi, help on this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745796/angular-material-to-select-mat-list-option-and-show-the-respective-data-of-the , thanks

Comment: Please don't request help for your own question on unrelated questions. You have done this on at least 3 of my answers now. I replied the first time saying that I try to avoid Material where possible. That's because I am not familar with Material, and I don't like the framework. I look at the open Angular questions, as do many other people. Your question may not have been satisfactorily answered yet because it is not clear enough. Spamming other answers isn't going to help you though, I'm afraid.

Comment: I look at open questions for 2 reasons. 1) StackOverflow has helped me a huge amount over the years. I want to help others who are learning. 2) Identifying other people's problems and giving a clear solution helps me improve my own skills. I enjoy doing it. If I have to put effort in to understand a low effort or confusing question, I've learned that it's not worth my time to try to work out the poster's requirements, because it leads to an unsatisfying experience. I'm not accusing you of anything here, I'm just explaining my general reasoning.

Comment: Having seen hundreds of questions recently, I can give you a little bit of advice about what makes a good question. 1) Do your research and give evidence for it 2) Try to abstract your problem into the simplest example possible. Don't just copy and paste your project code. This will also help you understand your problem. 3) Give a clear breakdown of the problem and the requirements for the solution.